# Deploy and run custom siddhi application

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator, wso2-cep

I am running *WSO2 Stream Processor 4.3.0*, I have created a siddhi application and I want to deploy and run this application on a worker in production.
I ran WSO2 SP worker profile with `"wso2-sp"` type, in `deployment.yml` file.
How can I ask the worker to run my custom siddhi application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your siddhi app in two ways.

1. Copy your **{siddhi_app_name}.siddhi** file to **{WSO2SP-HOME}/deployment/siddhi-files** directory. Then the siddhi app will be deployed automatically.
2. Use Siddhi App Rest API.

   Eg : 
   `curl -X POST "https://localhost:9443/siddhi-apps" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d @TestSiddhiApp.siddhi -u admin:admin -k`

   Refer to [Stream Processor REST API Guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Siddhi+Application+Management+APIs) for more details.

Comment: I put the `ei-analytics.siddhi` file into the mentioned folder. After sending _wso2events_ to the SP, I get this error: `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} - Dropping wrongly formatted event sent org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.esb.analytics.stream.FlowEntry:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:188)....`

Comment: Also by calling the curl request you mentioned, I get error it says can not file the app.

Comment: The siddhi app name is coming under EI-analytics artifacts condition. You have to rename it and deploy it or else enable EI Analytics solution in SP as per https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Analytics+Solutions